# Bootstrap Collapse tweening

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap Collapse plugin

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

My problem is I need to call a function on each transition step of the collapse as I need to reposition a sliding panel, similar to the JQuery Animate step functionality.

Is this possible?

Comment: The collapse plugin from Jasny Bootstrap is the same as the original from Twitter Bootstrap. I've rephrased this to a general Bootstrap question.